# Output to Speakers or headphones?

Tags: audio, wiring, speakers, headphones

I am going to be wiring up a custom circuit.  Audio is output from two LR audio cables.  I am going to wire them up to two mini speakers, one for each LR cord.  But how do I add in a part to detect if headphones are plugged in so instead of playing audio from the speakers it would play to the headphones that were plugged in?

Comment: Old headphone jacks have contacts that detect when the headphones are plugged in .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headphone jack sockets include switched contacts for exactly this purpose. See this schematic of a headphone socket:

[image]

So you would connect your source to pins 2 & 3, and your speakers to pins 4 and 5. As soon as the headphone is plugged in the speakers are disconnected.

Comment: Where can I buy one of these sockets to connect it up?

Comment: Depends where you are. Look up stereo headphone jack sockets on Google, 3.5mm are the most common size - used in phones etc. Hi-fi headphones use 1/4" 2.5mm also available, but not often used. Common suppliers are: arrow, maplin, rs components. Farnell, element 14, or digikey.